# getAmountsOut not works on BaseChain for V2 Router

Tags: solidity, etherscan, uniswap, revert

Is [0xD6e0Bc285be97C75861910f4d2cFD4AC61DD629d](https://basescan.org/address/0xd6e0bc285be97c75861910f4d2cfd4ac61dd629d) for V2 Router?

When I call `getAmountsOut`
it returns error:

```
Error: Returned error: execution reverted
```

[image]

But I can call `getPair` on [V2 Factory](https://basescan.org/address/0x8909Dc15e40173Ff4699343b6eB8132c65e18eC6#readContract):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with `getAmountsOut` function of the **Router** contract. However, in case of only one pair (i.e., two tokens), you can utilise the `getAmountOut` function (i.e., the same function used in loop inside the `getAmountsOut` function of **UniswapV2Library**), by passing in the corresponding `reserve` values for each of the tokens, that can be fetched from the **Pair** contract.

I've created the JS code to achieve the same:

```js
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const factoryAddress = "0x8909Dc15e40173Ff4699343b6eB8132c65e18eC6"

const routerAddress = "0xD6e0Bc285be97C75861910f4d2cFD4AC61DD629d"

const factoryAbi = [{ "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_feeToSetter", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "token0", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "token1", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "address", "name": "pair", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "PairCreated", "type": "event" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "allPairs", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "allPairsLength", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "tokenA", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "tokenB", "type": "address" }], "name": "createPair", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "pair", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "feeTo", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "feeToSetter", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "getPair", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_feeTo", "type": "address" }], "name": "setFeeTo", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_feeToSetter", "type": "address" }], "name": "setFeeToSetter", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }]

const routerAbi = [{ "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_factory", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "_WETH", "type": "address" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "WETH", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "tokenA", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "tokenB", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountADesired", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountBDesired", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountAMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountBMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "addLiquidity", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountA", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountB", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "liquidity", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "token", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountTokenDesired", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountTokenMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountETHMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "addLiquidityETH", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountToken", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountETH", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "liquidity", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "factory", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOut", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "reserveIn", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "reserveOut", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "getAmountIn", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "pure", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "reserveIn", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "reserveOut", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "getAmountOut", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOut", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "pure", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOut", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }], "name": "getAmountsIn", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }], "name": "getAmountsOut", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountA", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "reserveA", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "reserveB", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "quote", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountB", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "pure", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "tokenA", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "tokenB", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "liquidity", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountAMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountBMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "removeLiquidity", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountA", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountB", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "token", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "liquidity", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountTokenMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountETHMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "removeLiquidityETH", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountToken", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountETH", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "token", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "liquidity", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountTokenMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountETHMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountETH", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "token", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "liquidity", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountTokenMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountETHMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "bool", "name": "approveMax", "type": "bool" }, { "internalType": "uint8", "name": "v", "type": "uint8" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "r", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "s", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "removeLiquidityETHWithPermit", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountToken", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountETH", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "token", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "liquidity", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountTokenMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountETHMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "bool", "name": "approveMax", "type": "bool" }, { "internalType": "uint8", "name": "v", "type": "uint8" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "r", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "s", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountETH", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "tokenA", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "tokenB", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "liquidity", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountAMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountBMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "bool", "name": "approveMax", "type": "bool" }, { "internalType": "uint8", "name": "v", "type": "uint8" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "r", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "s", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "removeLiquidityWithPermit", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountA", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountB", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOut", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "swapETHForExactTokens", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]" }], "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOutMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "swapExactETHForTokens", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]" }], "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOutMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOutMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "swapExactTokensForETH", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOutMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOutMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "swapExactTokensForTokens", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOutMin", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOut", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountInMax", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "swapTokensForExactETH", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountOut", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountInMax", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "swapTokensForExactTokens", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "receive" }]

const pairAbi = [{ "inputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "owner", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Approval", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "sender", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount0", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount1", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }], "name": "Burn", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "sender", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount0", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount1", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Mint", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "sender", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount0In", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount1In", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount0Out", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount1Out", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }], "name": "Swap", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint112", "name": "reserve0", "type": "uint112" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint112", "name": "reserve1", "type": "uint112" }], "name": "Sync", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Transfer", "type": "event" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "DOMAIN_SEPARATOR", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "", "type": "bytes32" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "PERMIT_TYPEHASH", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "", "type": "bytes32" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "allowance", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "approve", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }], "name": "burn", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount0", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount1", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "decimals", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint8", "name": "", "type": "uint8" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "factory", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "getReserves", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint112", "name": "_reserve0", "type": "uint112" }, { "internalType": "uint112", "name": "_reserve1", "type": "uint112" }, { "internalType": "uint32", "name": "_blockTimestampLast", "type": "uint32" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_token0", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "_token1", "type": "address" }], "name": "initialize", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "kLast", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }], "name": "mint", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "liquidity", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "name", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "nonces", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "owner", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint8", "name": "v", "type": "uint8" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "r", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "s", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "permit", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "price0CumulativeLast", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "price1CumulativeLast", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }], "name": "skim", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount0Out", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount1Out", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "bytes", "name": "data", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "swap", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "symbol", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "sync", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "token0", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "token1", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "totalSupply", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transfer", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transferFrom", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }]

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://base-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/ALCHEMY_API_KEY");

const privateKey = "PRIVATE_KEY"; // Please never use your private key in plain text ever.

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

const factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(factoryAddress, factoryAbi, wallet);
const routerContract = new ethers.Contract(routerAddress, routerAbi, wallet);

const amountIn = '111111'   // In Wei
const tokenA = "0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006"
const tokenB = "0x8a5f9a6b653ecbdb406f9eb5f0c8ddba10919aec"

function sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB) {

    if (BigInt(tokenA) < BigInt(tokenB)) {
        return { token0: tokenA, token1: tokenB }
    }
    else {
        return { token0: tokenB, token1: tokenA }
    }
}

function getReservesInAndOut(reserve0, reserve1, token0) {
    if (tokenA == token0) {
        return { reserveIn: reserve0, reserveOut: reserve1 }
    }
    else {
        return { reserveIn: reserve1, reserveOut: reserve0 }
    }
}

factoryContract.getPair(tokenA, tokenB).then((pairAddress) => {
    // console.log(pairAddress)
    const pairContract = new ethers.Contract(pairAddress, pairAbi, wallet)
    pairContract.getReserves().then((reservesInfo) => {

        const { token0, token1 } = sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB)

        const reserve0 = reservesInfo._reserve0
        const reserve1 = reservesInfo._reserve1

        const { reserveIn, reserveOut } = getReservesInAndOut(reserve0, reserve1, token0)

        // console.log(token0, token1)
        // console.log(reserveIn, reserveOut)

        routerContract.getAmountOut(amountIn, reserveIn, reserveOut).then((amountOut) => {

            console.log('Amount In (In Wei): ', amountIn.toString())
            console.log('Amount Out (In Wei): ', amountOut.toString())
        })
    })
})
```